# Multiple Routes with Standard Router (Zend Framework)

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, router

I am trying to set up multiple routes to the same controller in zend as such:

```
URL                                            | Controller::Action
=================================================================================
http://mysite/tasks/:level/                    | Objectives::Objectives
http://mysite/tasks/:level/:objective/         | Objectives::tasks
http://mysite/tasks/:level/:objective/:taskID/ | Objectives::view
```

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
$router->addRoute('objectives', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'task/:level/:objective/:taskID/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'objectives',
        'action'     => 'view'
    )
));
$router->addRoute('objectives', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'task/:level/:objective/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'objectives',
        'action'     => 'tasks'
    )
));
$router->addRoute('objectives', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'task/:level/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'objectives',
        'action'     => 'tasks'
    )
));
?>
```

However the last rule seems to overwrite the previous rules in the router.. I've read the Zend Documentation for the router over and over, I have a feeling im just missing something - should I be using a different router class?

Any help is Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected I was overwriting the previous rules. The first argument for addRoute() is a name for the route, not the controller you are routing to as I thought. Giving each route a unique name fixed the problem.